# BufferedImage going out of bounds

Tags: java, image, graphics, awt, bufferedimage

I'm currently trying to create a shape which is filled with a solid color, which is then outputted as a PNG. This is my code.

```
void CreateRedImage(int xSize, int ySize, String FileName){
        BufferedImage bf = new BufferedImage(xSize, ySize, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Color color = new Color(225, 000, 000);
        File f = new File(FileName + ".png");
        bf.setRGB(xSize, ySize, color.getRGB());
        try {
            ImageIO.write(bf, "PNG", f);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately, when I run my code, I get this error message.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Coordinate out of bounds!
    at sun.awt.image.IntegerInterleavedRaster.setDataElements(IntegerInterleavedRaster.java:301)
    at java.awt.image.BufferedImage.setRGB(BufferedImage.java:988)
    at ImageCreation.CreateBlueImage(ImageCreation.java:53)
    at Main.main(Main.java:12)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

Now, I know the issue is with the line:

```
bf.setRGB(xSize, ySize, color.getRGB());
```

I've not been able to work out why my code isn't working though. Anyone got an idea?

Comment: what are the values `xSize`, `ySize` holding?

Comment: They're holding integer values that contain the coordinates for the x and y axis of the image. I'm passing in 10 for each parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) for `BufferedImage`'s **setRGB(int x, int y, int rgb)**, it says:-

> Sets a pixel in this BufferedImage to the specified RGB value. The
>   pixel is assumed to be in the default RGB color model, TYPE_INT_ARGB,
>   and default sRGB color space.

It also says that

> An ArrayOutOfBoundsException may be thrown if the coordinates are not in bounds. However, 
>   explicit bounds checking is not guaranteed.

which means that your `xSize` and `ySize` are not within the boundaries of the `BufferedImage`.

**Update:-**

From the docs again, if you carefully see the signature of the constructor of `BufferedImage` you happen to use, you'll see this:-

```
public BufferedImage(int width, int height, int imageType)
```

which means, in your case `xSize` and `ySize`, are the `width` and `height`, and its not necessary that your `BI`, should have the **co-ordinates(xSize, ySize)**. I hope you get the point here.

Comment: Ah. Would you agree that I'm not using Buffered Image appropriately then? At least for what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
bf.setRGB(xSize, ySize, color.getRGB());
```

setRGB is setting a single pixel, the x coord being 0 .. xSize - 1, the y coord like wise.

```
int c = color.getRGB();
for (int x = 0; x < xSize; ++x) {
    for (int y = 0; y < ySize; ++y) {
        bf.setRGB(x, y, color);
    }
}
```

Or

```
Graphics2D g = bf.createGraphics();
g.setColor(color);
g.fillRect(0, 0, xSize, ySize);
g.dispose();
```

Or better yet use the raster of BufferedImage.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like bf.getGraphics().fillRect(...)